# Performance on laravel

Tags: laravel

My laravel application loads to slow. I tried some improvement in the code, but only with minor succes.
I checked the load time with debugbar:
[image]

It sems ok.

If i open the development tools in safari, there i have the following timelines:

[image]

Why is there so a big difference? Does it gives an idea where i have to search to improve the performance?

Controller:

```
     $projects->load('type');
    $projects->load('customer');
    $projects->load('status');
    $jobTemplates = JobTemplate::allOrdered();
    $types = Type::all();
    $status = Status::all();

    $jobTransformed = Array();
    $jobs = Job::all();
    foreach ($jobs as $job)
    {
        $jobTransformed[$job->project_id][$job->jobTemplate_id] = $this->job($job);
    }

    return view('admin.cockpit')
        ->with('projects', $projects)
        ->with('jobTemplates' , $jobTemplates)
        ->with('jobs', $jobTransformed)
        ->with('status', $status)
        ->with('types', $types)
        ->with('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes )
        ->with('selectedStatus', $selectedStatus )
        ->with('selectedJob', $selectedJob )
        ->with('searchText', $searchText);
```

View:

```
<div class="panel-body table-responsive" style="height: 1000px">
                    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="cockpitTable" >
                        <thead style="font-weight: 700">
                            <tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                <th class="text-left"  style="background-color: white; font-weight: 700">Kunde</th>
                                <th class="text-left"  style="background-color: white ; font-weight: 700">Name</th>
                                <th class="text-left"  style="background-color: white; font-weight: 700">Type</th>
                                <th class="text-left" style="background-color: white; font-weight: 700">Status</th>
                                @foreach($jobTemplates as $jobTemplate)
                                    <th class="text-left">{{$jobTemplate->name}}</th>
                                @endforeach
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($projects as $project)
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-left" style="background-color: white">
                                        <a href="{{ route('admin.customers.show', $project->customer->id) }}">
                                            {!!   $project->customer->name!!} {!!   $project->customer->first_name!!}

                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-left"  style="background-color: white">
                                        <a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id) }}" >
                                          <strong>{!!   $project->name!!}</strong>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-left"  style="background-color: white">
                                        {!!   $project->type->name!!}
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-left"  style="background-color: white">
                                        <span class="label label-{{ $project->status->color }}">{!! $project->status->name !!}</span>
                                    </td>
                                    @foreach($jobTemplates as $jobTemplate)
                                        <td class="text-left " @if($jobTemplate->line_right) style="border-right: 1px solid; border-color: #ddd" @endif>
                                            @if(array_key_exists($project->id , $jobs))
                                                @if(array_key_exists($jobTemplate->id , $jobs[$project->id]))
                                                    {!! html_entity_decode($jobs[$project->id][$jobTemplate->id] )!!}
                                                @endif
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
```

Comment: Without any code its hard to tell. I would look at the 14 SQL-Queries. Reduce them and/or add missing indices.

Comment: Database queries tend to be the biggest bottleneck. I'd start by looking at them.

Comment: @Peter Did you setup relationships between you models?

Comment: first debugar it slows down the app much, then you have some foreach loops in blades which prolly some of them are causing N+1  issue. Try to use xhr requests instead.

Comment: @LeventeOtta yes i have  relationships

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi the application is also slow without debugbar

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shared view you don't need `$types` and `$status`, you can remove the DB calls as well. But I guess – since its the `admin.cockpit` –
 you just shared a part of the view.

Performance issues are hard to track without having a deeper knowledge of your code and the domain. Factors could be also the loading time of your Javascript. not using the browser cache for your assets or a long loading async JS process fetching some API.

As an admin cockpit should be fast I would create some Views in your DB which just stores the main information and gets updated by triggers. If this still not help, I would use a profile like [Blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io/) to find the bottleneck(s).

Thats beeing said I would look at:

```
foreach ($jobs as $job)
{
    $jobTransformed[$job->project_id][$job->jobTemplate_id] = $this->job($job);
}
```

Depending on how many jobs are in your DB you iterating over it and remap it every request.

Also this code:

```
<tr style="white-space: nowrap;">
<th class="text-left"  style="background-color: white; font-weight: 700">Kunde</th>
<th class="text-left"  style="background-color: white ; font-weight: 700">Name</th>
<th class="text-left"  style="background-color: white; font-weight: 700">Type</th>
<th class="text-left" style="background-color: white; font-weight: 700">Status</th>
@foreach($jobTemplates as $jobTemplate)
    <th class="text-left">{{$jobTemplate->name}}</th>
@endforeach
</tr>
```

and this one looks fishy to me.

```
@foreach($jobTemplates as $jobTemplate)
    <td class="text-left " @if($jobTemplate->line_right) style="border-right: 1px solid; border-color: #ddd" @endif>
        @if(array_key_exists($project->id , $jobs))
            @if(array_key_exists($jobTemplate->id , $jobs[$project->id]))
                {!! html_entity_decode($jobs[$project->id][$jobTemplate->id] )!!}
            @endif
        @endif
    </td>
@endforeach
```

You creating a table with potential endless columns (if the the amount of `$jobTemplates` is not restricted) and you looping over it twice.

Comment: Yes, it's only a part of the view
In the db, there are:
projects -> 150 rows
jobTemplates -> 22 rows
josb -> 3100 rows
I think i will store the jobs directly in the row of the project and update it when updating the project. I will let you know when i have results.
But i have still no idea with js to improve. But one step after the other...

Comment: I think it's the following plugin to fix the header and the first 4 columns in the table:
http://www.fixedheadertable.com
But no idea how to improve it

Answer (score 0):

From what i see on the screenshot, i suggest to load projects with the relationships in one query,

instead of

```
$projects->load('type');
$projects->load('customer');
$projects->load('status');
```

you can do :

```
$projects = Project::all()->with(['type', 'customer', 'status']);
```